# How to set VBA range of merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i am currently using:

```
Set Description = RCA.Range("D24:G24")
```

But i have merged cells D24 and D25:G24 and G25

How do i set the range to encapsulate D25 and G25 area too?

Comment: RCA.Range("D24:G25")? please provide clarification on the meaning of `encapsulate D25 and G25 area`

Comment: Why do you want to merge cells? It’s bony advisable.

Comment: The range `D25:G24`, or more user-friendly `D24:G25`, already contains the cells `D24`, `D25`, and `G25`. Please edit your question, correct the range references and 
 share what exactly is merged. If the merged range is `D24:G24`, to include `D25` and `G25`, you could use `.Range("D24:D25,G25")` or `.Range("D24,D25,G25")`. Note that you cannot copy such a range (using the *Range.Copy* method).

Comment: The range obtained from "D24 and D25:G24 and G25" will be Range("D24:G25"), but **if you need to use its value** you should use `Debug.Print Range("D4").Value`. A merge cells range **keep its value in its top left cell**. If you want to obtain a discontinuous range, follow the above suggestion. `Range("D24:D25, F25")`, which **cannot be merged**. Placing "G25" at the end, it will become "D24:G25". But, **how to you intend to use it**? Do you understand what a merged cells range is, no offence?